# How to update many to many relationship by using skip navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, ef-core-7.0

i'm using .NET 6 version with EF Core 7.
I defined two entities :

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Language> Languages { get; set; }
}

// One language -> Many Countries
public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

My DB context has a many to many relationship definition :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>
                      .HasMany(_ => _.Languages)
                      .WithMany(_ => _.Countries);
```

Under the hood , EF Core creates linkage table CountryLanguage.
For example I have a country with ID = 1 and languages with IDs : 1, 2,3 and lets say Country with ID 1 is currently linked to Language with ID 1. It means table CountryLanguage has one row with CountryId = 1 and LanguageId =1.

Now i want to change it , that Country with ID = 1 will be linked to Languages with IDs : 2 and 3.
But when i try to use Update method of DbSet for Country it adds new links but the previous link is not deleted and the result
i got Country with ID=1 which is linked to Languages with IDs :1, 2 and 3.
It means table CountryLanguage has now three rows with CountryId = 1 and LanguageId =1, CountryId = 1 and LanguageId =2 and
CountryId = 1 and LanguageId =3.

The desired behavior was to get Country with ID=1   which is linked to Languages with IDs : 2 and 3 only.
Please, help me to figure out how to do it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your code with us?

Looks like you are just adding new item to the `Country.Languages`. To remove the existing relationship, you'll need to do it manually. For example: `_dbContext.Languages.Remove(languageItemToRemove);`

Finally, do not forget to use `_dbContext.SaveChanges();`.